# Using SPST Switch as Button using Capacitor, which type?

Tags: pulse, encoder, electrolytic-capacitor, toggle-switch

Before I start, know that I'm still very much a beginner at electrical engineering. I'm building a switch box to be used for PC simulators using mainly (non-momentary) SPST switches and a USB encoder.

However, most games/sims can't use these kind of switches as pulses, as they are on-off rather than pulse-pulse.

I could use one of the dual pulse encoders sold by "Desktop Aviator," but According to [this](https://www.flightsim.com/vbfs/content.php?2178) article, you can also use a capacitor to create the same pulse effect whenever the switch is toggled. But, it only says "47uF." Which voltage though? Would any work? The pulse should be under one second. A̶g̶a̶i̶n Obviously, I'm very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize the solution you linked to uses a capacitor and a relay - the latter emulating the keyboard switch? With the cost of a relay included, I cannot imagine it wouldn't be cheaper to replace the SPST switches.

Comment: *Oh...* not sure how I missed that, haha. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage rating of the chosen capacitor just needs to be greater than whatever logic voltage you are working at (e.g. 5 volt). Using a 100V capacitor in a low voltage circuit won’t do any harm.